# Tomcat view connector settings being used

Tags: tomcat, troubleshooting

Is there a way to view what settings are set for a connector at runtime?

For instance, I want to see what maxConnections is set to.

Pretty much verify all these settings:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to tomcat manager?

If so, you could go to your server like http://example.com/manager/status/all?XML=true or http://example.com/manager/status/all. Here you have a couple of information about the connectors.

To activate tomcat manager go to your folder *$TOMCAT_HOME/conf* and edit *tomcat-users.xml* to look like this:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
```

After that restart your tomcat and go to http://example.com/manager where you could login with user *tomcat* and password *secret*